# slick.js как удалить слайд по определенному индексу

Tags: jquery, slick.js

как можно удалить слайд по определенному индексу, пробовал вот таких способом но не удаляет, как это можно сделать?

```
var ind = 2;
$(".slider").slick("slickRemove", $(".slider").find(".slick-slide").index(ind);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ind = 2;    
$('.slider').slick('slickRemove', $('.slick-slide').index(ind) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

да вот так срабатывает

```
var ind = 2;    
$('.slider').slick('slickRemove', ind-1);
```